# is it possible to transfer a class object as hidden variable from JSP to action

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am using `Struts 1.x` as my framework,

Here I have situation like I need to pass my custom class object as Hidden variable Like I want to do something like below

```
  <html:form name="FormName">
   <html:hidden property="ClassObject" value="<%=new MyClass() %>" >
  </html:form>
```

I my `FormName` form I have created getters and setters for `ClassObject` as shown below.

```
     private MyClassObject ClassObject; 

     public MyClassObject getClassObject()
       {
             return ClassObject;
              }
      //setter also I have created
```

So In my action class I am trying to get that `ClassObject` as below

```
      MyClassObject obj = ((FormName) form).getClassObject();
```

But when I do like this I am getting  error as Unable to crate class for JSP at line

```
      `<html:hidden property="ClassObject" value="<%=new MyClass() %>" >`
```

My doubt is: Is it possible to carru objects like that if so Where I am mistaking ?

```
         If not What is the best way to pass Object from JSP to action ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you even want to do this?

Comment: I need to transfer some data of various variables in that object to action anyway It seems that I can not pass object to action like this way..

Comment: maybe use ajax and pass the variables in json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,Because whatever you are sending from client side is just html not any objects.Request only having set of Strings like (Header,QueryString and body etc).

To pass Human Object to Servler Side from client you can use JSON.Otherwise go with Session.

JSON:

```
Class Human
{
private int id;
privae String name;
// other attributes etc
}
```

`[{id:"",name:""}]`---this is String but you can bring that using JSON related APIs.

*P.S :JSON related idea got from Scary.*

Comment: Thanks dude.. I will use Session I guess Thanks